# Como pongo código html (no compilado) en laTex?

Tags: latex

Quería poner un ejemplo de código en laTex, pero me salia esto:

```
¡DOCTYPE html¿ ¡html¿ ¡body¿ ¡p¿Hola¡/p¿ ¡/body¿ ¡/html¿
```

cuando lo que yo quería era esto:

```
<DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
          <body>
            <p>Hola</p>
          </body>
        </html>
```

Que extensión puedo utilizar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al final he averiguado un par de extensiones que van bien para escribir código latex.

> ## Paquetes
>
> 1. `Listings`. Esta extensión permite escribir código html, css, javascript...etc. Aunque puedes personalizar el color, creo que minted és una opción mejor
> 2. `Minted`. Minted utiliza el paquete de latex `pygments`. Es mucho más complejo de instalar, y además incluye `Python`, pero admite más lenguajes de programación que `Listings`.
> 3. `Verbments`. Verbments también usa el paquete `pygments`, tiene una configuración más sencilla que `minted`, y es más adecuada que `minted` para escribir documentos sencillos con código.

> ## Implentar los paquetes al documento `latex`
>
> Para implantar los paquetes en tu documento latex, hace falta cargarlos con la siguiente instrución:
> `\usepackage{nombredelpaquete}`
> donde "nombredelpaquete" és el paquete que quieres cargar. Por ejemplo, si quieres usar el paquete `Minted`, lo que tendrás que hacer és:
> `\usepackage{minted}`
> (no garantizo que este configurado por defecto, ya que uso más `listings`)